# Where does default USER PROFILE for the Internet Explorer lives and how do I access it from Selenium?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

Each time I run a test, I get a new instance of IE, which completely ignore all my settings. I solve the same problem in **Firefox** and **Chrome** by setting the option for those browsers to look for a specific **user profile**.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(path/to/profile");
public static readonly IWebDriver WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

This is how the path to a user profile looks like in **Firefox**:

```
@"C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\t1hjw29h.WatirWebDriver"
```

I'd like in which folder the **user profile** lives in **Internet Explorer** and how to access it from **Selenium**.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After straggling with this problem for days, I've finally found a [solution on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51iuVOHGUHs) which helped me solve it, at least when it comes to Internet Explorer. I'm still looking for an appropriate solution in Chrome.

1. One need to download [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) as it said in the video
2. write an AutoIT script, save it, and compile it to produce a executable file as shown in the video
3. Add an command to execute the AutoIT in the context of your automation.

The last step in the most critical of all. In my case, I've put in the Open Method because it's when I open a page that I get prompted with a authentication popup.

```
   public virtual void Open(
        string urlParam = "")
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ExpectedPageUrl.Replace("{0}", urlParam));
        Process.Start("path to my AutoIT executable file\BasicAuth.exe");
        Wait(3);
    }
```

My AutoIT executable file is called **BasicAuth.exe**. Now it's working perfectly, i.e. I'm able to run a test on pages that require credentials.